# Finding the next type of element after a selector in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am hoping to get some help with finding the next type of an element after finding an image with ends a specific way. So far, I've got it locating the images and beginning to run an each() function, but I can't get it to select the next input on the page.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
$("img[src$='sunglasses.jpg']").each(function( index ) {
$( this ).closest(".label_box").find("input[name^=happy_]").prop('value', '1');
$( this ).nextAll("input[name^=happy_").eq(0).prop('value', '1');
});
```

And an example of the HTML would be something like this:

```
<div class="image_box">
<img src="sunglasses.jpg">
</div>
<div class="label_box">
<input name="happy_1">
</div>
```

Essentially, I'm trying to select the input of happy_* in another div directly after finding a matching image.

Comment: .next/.nextAll only looks at siblings, as your input isn't a sibling it will never find it.  Best option is to go up to a common wrapper (not shown in your html) then use `.find` to go back down.  Classes will help instead of `[name^=happy_`

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I figured it out! I just needed to add 2 .parent() functions to get up tot he correct div.

```
$(this).parent().parent().next('div').find("input[name^=happy_]")
```